# jQuery Toggle Div - how to leave div open on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code which works fine:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.text').hide();
    $('.expander').click(function () {
        // .parent() selects the A tag, .next() selects the P tag
        $(this).parent().next().slideToggle(200);
    });
    $('.text').slideUp(200);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"><div class="expander">Click Here</div></a>

<p class="text">Hidden Text</p>
<a href="#"><div class="expander">Click Here</div></a>

<p class="text">Hidden Text</p>
<a href="#"><div class="expander">Click Here</div></a>

<p class="text">Hidden Text</p>
<a href="#"><div class="expander">Click Here</div></a>

<p class="text">Hidden Text</p>
```

However - I wondered if there is a way to change the jQuery so that the content in the DIVs is visible when the page first loads, rather than hidden as currently happens.

I tried commenting out this line:

```
$('.text').hide();
```

But it made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove/comment out `$('.text').slideUp(200);` and `$('.text').hide();`.

These are the two lines  which are hiding the "Hidden text". They both does the same thing, hides the matched elements. `.hide()` hides the element as the name depicts. And `.slideUp` does the same by making he `heigh` zero of the matched element so hides the element

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.
Your jQuery will be cleaner this way.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.expander').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().next().slideToggle(200);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"><div class="expander">Click Here</div></a>
<p class="text">Hidden Text</p>
<a href="#"><div class="expander">Click Here</div></a>
<p class="text">Hidden Text</p>
<a href="#"><div class="expander">Click Here</div></a>
<p class="text">Hidden Text</p>
<a href="#"><div class="expander">Click Here</div></a>
<p class="text">Hidden Text</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two function hiding `$('.text')`

commenting them out would work as expected.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // $('.text').hide();
    $('.expander').click(function () {
        // .parent() selects the A tag, .next() selects the P tag
        $(this).parent().next().slideToggle(200);
    });
    // $('.text').slideUp(200);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"><div class="expander">Click Here</div></a>

<p class="text">Hidden Text</p>
<a href="#"><div class="expander">Click Here</div></a>

<p class="text">Hidden Text</p>
<a href="#"><div class="expander">Click Here</div></a>

<p class="text">Hidden Text</p>
<a href="#"><div class="expander">Click Here</div></a>

<p class="text">Hidden Text</p>
```